# Terminal having trouble displaying histograms

Tags: python, pandas

I am working through some coursework and when I run the required code in a terminal window I do not get an output of a histogram like the book says I should.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    bank_train = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/Data/bank_marketing_training")
    bank_train['index'] = pd.Series(range(0,26874))
    bank_train['days_since_previous'] = bank_train['days_since_previous'].replace({999: np.NaN})
    bank_train['days_since_previous'].plot(kind = 'hist', title = 'Histogram of Days Since Previous')
```

For the output I get:

```
<AxesSubplot:title={'center':'Histogram of Days Since Previous'}, ylabel='Frequency'>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` at the end of your code.

Comment: thanks for that! the histogram popped up with that last bit of code.